# Making site running in XAMPP 7 in OS X accessible over local network (LAN)

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I have a site running on XAMPP server in my OS X platform, and would like to make it accessible from other machines on our network. When I search for this, I find a lot of information on older versions of XAMPP (and some stuff related to the Windows version.)

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to), but XAMPP looks like it has changed quite a bit, as the interface looks quite different. I went a bit crosseyed at all the options. I'm using version 7.3.5 for OS X.

[image]

Also, I'm not sure why I needed to do this, but I had to enable port forwarding `localhost:8080->80(Over SSH)` to make the site accessible on my own machine. I literally was just trying things at the point that I found that. This requires that I use `localhost:8080` in my URL. It works, but this is not consistent with the tutorial I'm following, and I don't know how to get it working without that.

[image]

I am new to XAMPP, and don't have much experience with Apache, so any elaboration will be appreciated.

BTW, this question has brought me to asking a question on Meta Stack Exchange about [how to deal with questions that might get more attention on Stack Overflow, when more appropriate for another board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329334/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-might-get-more-attention-on-stack-overflow-when).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take everything below with a grain of salt. =)

> I'm not sure why I needed to do this, but I had to enable port forwarding `localhost:8080 -> 80 (Over SSH)` to make the site accessible on my own machine.

According to this [Apache Friends Blog Post on XAMPP-VM for Mac](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html), it looks like XAMMP for Mac is running in an isolated virtual machine (VM). This "virtual machine" is a software environment that keeps XAMMP (i.e. its processes, such as Apache) separate from the host operating system (e.g. your Mac).

The reason port forwarding in the XAMMP interface is required seems to be because any port below `1024` is considered a privileged port on *NIX style systems (such as Mac and Linux). "Privileged port" in this case means that a process (such as `httpd.exe` a.k.a. Apache) needs  to be run as `root` to bind to it (use it for communication).

So rather than having end-users fiddling with their systems to run Apache on port `80` via XAMPP, the developers at Apache Friends have provided an interface to the web server on a non-privileged port (`8080`).

---

*Note that there is also a secondary issue with the fact that MacOS already comes with a pre-installed version of Apache which runs on port `80` by default. These two versions of Apache cannot use the same port.*

---

> I would like to make [Apache] accessible from other machines on our network.

Since you have Apache working, the general steps would likely be:

1. Ensure that any host machine firewall (i.e. on your Mac) isn't blocking port `80` and/or port `8080`. This also technically goes for any external firewalls as well.
2. It may be necessary (depending on circumstances) to disable the default installation of Apache semi-permanently (this [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119674/disable-apache-autostart/119678) question may provide hints on how to go about this).
3. Set up forwarding from port `80` to port `8080`. You may wish to do this on the Mac itself so you can drop the `:8080` from your URL (perhaps have a look at this [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37418/how-can-i-open-port-80-so-a-non-root-process-can-bind-to-it/46804) question). The other option may be to forward incoming port `80` to `8080` on `Your_Mac_IP` in the router for the network (depending on how your network is set up).